# How can I bind a xaml property to a static variable in another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this xaml file in which I try to bind a Text-block Background to a static variable in another class, how can I achieve this ?

I know this might be silly but I just moved from Win-forms and feeling a little bit lost.

here is what I mean:

```
<TextBlock Text="some text"
           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
           Background="{Binding Path=SomeVariable}" />
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

First of all you can't bind to `variable`. You can bind only to `properties` from XAML.
For binding to static property you can do in this way (say you want to bind `Text` property of `TextBlock`) -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:YourClassName.PropertyName}}"/>
```

where `local` is namespace where your class resides which you need to declare above in xaml file like this -

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
```

Comment: Check your `Output` window. There might be some binding issue log there.

Comment: Have you make the variable `Property`?

Comment: Aha its a converter issue it tells me that i can't assign Color to a Brush and should use a converter in normal c# code we used to do something like this 

textblock.BackGround = new SolidColorBrush(GivenColor);

Comment: but still lost and don't know how to achieve that either !

Comment: Return brush from your converter - `return new SolidColorBrush(value as Color)`

Comment: I guess this working with a bindable properties  , right ??

Answer (score 16):

You can't actually bind to a static property (INotifyPropertyChanged makes sense on instances only), so this should be enough...

```
{x:Static my:MyTestStaticClass.MyProperty}
```

or e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static my:MyTestStaticClass.MyProperty}" Width="500" Height="100" />
```

make sure you include the `namespace` - i.e. define the `my` in the XAML like `xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`

---

**EDIT: binding from code**
(There're some mixed answers on this part so I thought it made sense to expand, have it in one place)

---

### `OneTime` binding:

You could just use `textBlock.Text = MyStaticClass.Left` (just careful where you place that, post-init)

### `TwoWay` (or `OneWayToSource`) binding:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
//binding.Source = typeof(MyStaticClass);
// System.InvalidOperationException: 'Binding.StaticSource cannot be set while using Binding.Source.'
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(MyStaticClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyStaticClass.Left)));
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
this.SetBinding(Window.LeftProperty, binding);
```

...of course if you're setting Binding from the code remove any bindings in XAML.

### `OneWay` (property changes from the source):

And if you'd need to update the target (i.e. the control's property, Window.Left in this case) on the source property changes, that can't be achieved with the static class (as per my comment above, you'd need the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented, so you could just use a wrapper class, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and wire that to a static property of your interest (providing you know how to track you static property's changes, i.e. this is more of a 'design' issue from this point on, I'd suggest redesigning and putting it all within one 'non-static' class).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @jbyrd which way do you want to bind from static property to control, or to static, or two way?

Comment: @NSGaga - from control to static property.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not the answer by @RohitVats

Answer (score 2):

You can use the newer `x:Bind` to do this simply using:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind YourClassName.PropertyName}"/>
```

Comment: x:Bind is not available in WPF, that's UWP that you're talking about